# Schema for arrays inside array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection to like below. I want to design a schema in mongoose...

```
   {
   "_id" : ObjectId("51da6e03e6d8e40aa4c72c28"),
     "series" : [{
  "type" : "pie",
  "name" : "Browser share",
  "data" : [["Firefox", 45.0], ["IE", 26.8], ["Safari", 8.5], ["Opera", 6.2], ["Others",    0.7]]
}]
}
```

My mongoose code is :

```
_id: false,
   series: [{
    type:String,
    name: String,
    data:[]
}]
```

But I am not getting that data using this schema. I am getting a blank array but I want the same data that is in that collection. Please suggest some schema structure and how I can fetch the same data using node.

this is the way i m fetching data, But i am not able to get the data:
          query.fetchAll(schData.schTempPI, null, function (err, result) {

```
    console.log(result.series);

    var data = chartModel.data;
    for (i = 0; i < result[0].series.length; i++) {
        data.series.push(result[0].series[i])
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to accomplish what you mean to, your schema should actually be:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  _id: false,
  series: {
    type: String,
    name: String,
    data: [
      [String, Number]
    ]
  }
});
```

Or something similar. This is untested, but based on the docs I believe this is something more like what you should be going for... You could also look into [SubDocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).